# What kind of pins are used on the end of a force sensitive resistor strip? How can I fix a strip with broken pins?

Tags: resistors, repair

I have two [force sensitive resistor strips from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9674) where the pins have been damaged.

[image: force sensitive resistor strip pins]

(One of the pins melted off when I heated it up too much with a soldering iron. The other got ripped out by accident.)

The strips are a bit expensive ($25 each) so I would like to fix them.

What is the name for these kinds of pin that can be crimped onto the strip and connect to the trace? Or is there some other kind of connector where I could clip it on, and it punches through the strip to make a connection? I wouldn't mind something a bit stronger and more reliable than the original pins.

Thanks!

Comment: i found these on the same page. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14194 https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14195

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need! I will order some replacement strips and use these instead.

Comment: those connectors may actually connect to the damaged strip, for connectiong to new strips use regular 2.54mm square pin header sockets,  or female "duPont" wires. you can get 2 pin sockets, or just glue two single pin sockets together,

Answer (score 2):

Having worked with a similar strip before: you can try to crimp anything to the printed-on conductive (grey) trace, but it will never even come close to the original device's durability, and more importantly, resistance and reliability of contact. Especially not if your investment costs are bounded by $25.

So, I'd buy a new strip (sorry!) but this time avoided putting thermal and mechanical stress on these pins. My sensor hat differently shaped contacts, but these look like they are compatible with 2mm spade connectors (do measure the width, so, something like [this](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/vdadf1.25-110a-8/insulated-terminals/jst/vdadf1-25-110a-8-rd-s-lf-k/) might work as plug to connect cables to:

[image: flat female spade connector]

you simply crimp a wire into the plastic-mantled tube (with normal pliers, even).

If the distance between the centers of the two pins happen to be "electronics-standard", i.e., something like 1.25 mm, 2.0mm, …,  2.54 mm, there might be "FPC connectors" that [fit the problem](https://www.digikey.de/en/products/filter/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connector-assemblies/399?s=N4IgjCBcoBw1oDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQB7KAbXACYwBmcgNhAF0CAHAFyhAGVWAnASwB2AcxABfAjACcCEMkjps%2BIqRAwALFJATJVKlpCSA7HX2TJa%2BkxBsO3fsLEEwkzdFmpMuAsUhkADIziIAC05DJyvACuSj5kAKyBQfRufAAmHMFgfhAs7JAg%2BgCOrACeHFn6pcw4HGhYyKKiQA) as well. You'd want to solder them onto a board.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have ordered some replacement strips and will be more careful with the connector this time! I might wrap it with tape or 3D print an enclosure to ensure that I don't accidentally rip the pins off, because they are quite weak. Thanks!